# Django: Reverse for '*' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{a,b}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['order/pay/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have to views. One that triggers an overview of a guest's orders. And one that sets an order to paid and then should go back to the overview:

```
@login_required
def guest_detail(request, pk):
    guest = get_object_or_404(Guest, pk=pk)
    open_orders = Order.objects.filter(guest = guest, is_paid=False)
    paid_orders = Order.objects.filter(guest = guest, is_paid=True)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterGuestForm(request.POST, instance=guest)
        if form.is_valid():
            guest = form.save(commit=False)
            guest.save()
            #post.published_date = timezone.now()
            return redirect('guest_detail', pk=guest.pk)
    else:
            form = RegisterGuestForm(instance=guest)
    context = {'form': form}
    context['open_orders'] = open_orders
    context['paid_orders'] = paid_orders
    return render(request, 'hotel/guest_detail.html', context)
```

This view is rendered to this template:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
  <h3>Guest Information:</h3>
  <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save-guest btn btn-default">Save</button>
  </form>
  <h3>Open orders:</h3>
  <table class="table table-condensed table-guest-order">
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th><th>
    </tr>
   {% for order in open_orders %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{ order.date }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.amount }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.item }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.price }}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'pay_order' pk=order.pk order_guest=order.guest.pk %}">pay</a></td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
 </table>
</div>
```

The pay_order link then calls the following view, which should then redirect me back, to where I come from:

```
@login_required
def pay_order(request, *args, **kwargs):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    if order.is_paid is False:
        order.is_paid = True
        order.paid_date = timezone.now()
        order.save()
    return redirect(views.guest_detail, pk=kwargs['order_guest'])
```

But I receive this error

> Reverse for 'pay_order' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{'order_guest': 10, 'pk': 19}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['order/pay/(?P\d+)/$']

this is the urls.py used:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^rooms/$', views.ListRoomsView.as_view(), name='rooms'),
    url(r'^service/$', views.service, name='service'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^guests/$', views.ListGuestsView.as_view(), name='guests'),
    url(r'^guests/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.guest_detail, name='guest_detail'),
    url(r'^register_guest/$', views.register_guest, name='register_guest'),
    url(r'^order/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.order_detail, name='order'),
    url(r'^order/$', views.register_order, name='new_order'),
    url(r'^order/list/$', views.ListOrdersView.as_view(), name='open_orders'),
    url(r'^order/pay/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.pay_order, name='pay_order'),

    ]
```

when I call the guest_detail view for a guest who has open payments. If a guest has no open payments everything works fine. So I presume the problem is the way I try to pass the pk of the guest to the pay_order view.

Comment: Since the error is with reversing URLs, you should show your urls.py.

Comment: added it below. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass a parameter for "order_guest" to the `pay_order` view, but the URL is not expecting that parameter, and neither is the view using it. You shouldn't pass it at all; take that out of the values in the `{% url %}` tag.

```
<a href="{% url 'pay_order' pk=order.pk %}">pay</a>
```

Comment: Maybe my reasoning is wrong... But the pay_order view redirects to the guest_detail view which needs guest.pk as input. So I have to pass this to pay_order, right? The question is, how can I make my pay_order view accept order_guest?

Comment: Why not the same way as you got it to accept pk? It's just another parameter in the URL.